# DLL not found in folder specified in %PATH% by Pathon

Tags: python, dll

I wrote a Python module using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) that dynamically links to the hdf5 library. When I copy the hdf5 dlls into the output directory, I can load my python module. If not, python complains about some specified procedure that could not be found. However, the path to the dlls is in the `%PATH%` variable if I call it via `echo %PATH%`.

Why do I still need to copy the dlls?

Comment: It's probably finding a different version of one of the DLLs in `PATH` or the application directory (e.g. where python.exe is located), a system directory, or the working directory. The application directory, system directories, and the working directory are searched before `PATH`, and then `PATH` is searched in order. Check `where [filename]` for each of the hdf5 DLLs to see if it's a problem that can be resolved by modifying `PATH`.

Comment: Ok, so with the `where` command I get 1) HDF folder, 2) Anaconda3 folder

Comment: Is the Anaconda3 folder also the application directory, i.e. where python.exe is located? If so, it gets searched before `PATH`.

Comment: And when I copy the files from the anaconda folder to the working directory I get the same error message, so it seems it is using these libraries instead of the ones in the hdf5 folder.

Comment: It's a subfolder

Comment: Print `os.environ['PATH']` to see whether Anaconda modifies it at startup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142586/discussion-between-mr-z-and-eryksun).

Comment: As you can see I gave up with the issue. If you have a smarter answer feel free to post it. I will definitely choose it over mine which is not a real "solution" but more a "it works" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as eryksun in his comments suggested the issue is with Anaconda modifying the PATH environment when Python is loaded. Since Anaconda does not use the latest hdf5, these libraries are incompatible with the ones I built against.

I uninstalled HDF5 and just use the libraries provided with Anaconda. This works, but is not perfect. For once Anaconda libs are not compiled with Debug symbols, which can be inconvenient, and also Anaconda comes with an older version of HDF5 so I have to be careful when developing on other platforms where I don't use Anaconda to not use newer HDF5 features.